# Tripod and camera

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod

Can any tripod be used for any camera?If no,can anyone suggest me a tripod for Canon SX 150 IS.(http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/digital_cameras/other_powershot/powershot_sx150_is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a very light-weight camera, pretty much every tripos will work with your camera.

You need to be certain the tripod (and its head) can hold the weight of your camera.

Set a budget and shop around; there are dozen of different brands and models.

You need to look for a good stable tripod, the heavier you can find that fits your requirements the better it will be, the more stable it will be.

You do not want to the camera to move when on the tripod.

The screw on the tripod head is standard and will fit every camera.